# Special characters substitution stopped working in Kile (compose key)

Tags: keyboard-layout, latex, special-characters, kile

This question is a duplicate of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571527/special-characters-and-compose-key-in-kile) on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange, but, since I strongly suspect that my problem is due to a bug in KDE/Kile, I thought it would be appropriate here as well. So here we go.

I've been using Kile (with various Ubuntu distributions) for ages without any problem to write math papers. Now, for some reason, I was recently forced to upgrade my system to Ubuntu 20.04 and this created a new annoying problem in Kile 2.9.93.

**Context**: I often have to use special characters, typically French accents such as *à,è,è,î* etc. Since I'm using a US keyboard layout on my laptop, I'm efficiently and successfully using the KDE "compose key" feature to type those throughout my whole operating system: inputting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> results in *é*, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> results in *ï* and so on... I want Kile to automatically substitute these (virtually, indirectly inputted) special characters by their LaTex equivalent, which fortunately exists as an amazingly useful built-in feature of Kile. This was working fine until now.

**Problem**: Since my last upgrade to 20.04 this doesn't work anymore. What is really weird is that if I disable the "substitute special characters" in Kile and input any of my compose-key combinations (say, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>) then Kile does recognize the input and correctly displays *é* in the editor. So this bug appears to be caused by the interaction of the "substitute special characters" Kile feature with the "compose key" KDE feature.

Has anyone encountered the same issue? And does anyone have any solution? Of course I can always manually input the LaTex command `\'e` for *é* and so on, but after 15 years of practice I doubt that my muscle memory would be too happy. Also, what a waste of time!

Comment: I had have same problem with accents in Ubuntu 22.04. I don't know what is the answer, but your question let me  resolve my problems with accents! thanks